# How to test observer in foreground state for notife.onForegroundEvent in react-native using jest

Tags: react-native, callback, notifications, ts-jest, foreground

this is the method which listens the foreground notification event

```
   ` notifee.onForegroundEvent(({ type, detail }) => {
        switch (type) {
          case EventType.DISMISSED:
            console.log("User dismissed notification", detail.notification?.android);
            break;
          case EventType.PRESS:
            if (detail?.notification?.title?.toLocaleLowerCase().includes('new friend      request')) {
            }
            break;
        }
      });`
```

how we can test this in jest ? because its require app to be foreground.

i had tried to mock this callback

```
  `jest.mock('@notifee/react-native', () => {

  mockForeground=jest.fn(),
  mockBackground=jest.fn()
  var EventType={
    DISMISSED:0
  }
  return{
    onForegroundEvent:jest.fn().mockImplementationOnce(() =>  jest.fn().mockResolvedValueOnce({type:EventType.DISMISSED,detail:mockResponse}))
  }
});`
```

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@notifee/react-native this is the package for reference